# Visual Studio 2019 template not showing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I downloaded the Bot framework SDK V4 and installed it on Visual Studio 2019.
[image]

[image]
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4

But I cannot see the template when I create a new project.
[image]

I even see the template installed in Extensions
[image]

Comment: Yes. I restarted even a couple of time but still not showing

Comment: It is a fresh install of visual studio 2019

Comment: I did not install any workloads. Do I need to install one to get The Bot framework showing ?